# Clarification on smart pointer's operator* and operator-> overloading

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

it's passed a lot since i used c++ so here the(probally dumb) question:

A basic smart pointer Object should behave like a normal pointer one, so in a typical implementation we add the `*` and `->` operator to the object, something like this:

```
template <class T> class auto_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
    public:
    explicit auto_ptr(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
    ~auto_ptr()                 {delete ptr;}
    T& operator*()              {return *ptr;}
    T* operator->()             {return ptr;}
   // ...
};
```

Now, in my knowings, the c++ `*` operator (dereference) stands for: "get the value pointed in the heap by the value of ptr" (is it right?), and the type of `*ptr` should be `T`. So why we would return an address?

```
T& operator*()              {return *ptr;}
```

Instead of:

```
T operator*()              {return *ptr;}
```

Second, by having the following snippet:

```
void foo()
{
    auto_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass);
    p->DoSomething();
}
```

Now, how can i access `ptr->DoSomething()` method by just writing `p->DoSomething()`? Logically i would come writing the wrong code:

```
p->->DoSomething();
```

Because `p->` returns a `T*` and then i need another `->` operator for access the `DoSomething()` method.

Thanks for any answer/clarification and sorry for eventually bad English.

Comment: Pointers don't have to point to the heap.

Comment: You're not "returning an address". That's not how C++ works. Please get a book.

Comment: An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()`
exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, when you evaluate a function, you end up with a value (unless the function's return type is `void`). The type of a value is always an object type. So when you say `f()`, that expression is a value of type `T`. However, there are different *categories* of value:

```
T    f();    =>   f() is a prvalue, passed along by copy
T &  f();    =>   f() is an lvalue, the same object that is bound to "return"
T && f();    =>   f() is an xvalue, the same object that is bound to "return"
```

So if you want a function to produce an existing value that you don't want to copy, you have to declare the return type of the function as one of the reference types. If the return type is not a reference type, then a copy of the return value will be made, and the caller only ever sees that copy.

Comment: I have recently seen many people have the confusion about such question. The explanation in [c++ programming language](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxZQ7C2bC9x1Tm5HbklDV0pBdUk/edit) may be helpful

Comment: Thx Kerrek and you all guys, days ago, me and my friends laughed so much while reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

The dereference operator returns a *reference* because then you can do e.g.

```
*somePointer = someValue;
```

and the value of what `somePointer` points to would change to `someValue`. If you returned by value, the above expression would have a temporary value that is assigned to, and then that temporary value is destructed and the change is lost.

Comment: You can't really "return a reference". Function evaluation is always a value, and values are never references... just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't have to write `p->->DoSomething` is that `operator->` recurses until it finds something that isn't a pointer, `T*`.

`p->` finds `T*` which is a pointer so it goes down another level and finds a `MyClass`-object, so it stops and does a normal `operator.` on that.

Note that smart pointers aren't considered pointers in this case.

Comment: `operator->` _recurses until it finds something that isn't a pointer_: Can you point me to any references or standard sections to understand this?

Comment: yuans comment to the OP summarised it better than I did.

Comment: +1 Found it ~ N3337 draft _§13.3.1.2/8_: If the value returned by the operator-> function has class type, this may result in selecting and calling another operator-> function. The process repeats until an operator-> function returns a value of non-class type.

Comment: Thanks, so far I haven't been able to find it myself.